# CUDA: Summation of results

Tags: cuda

I'm using CUDA to run a problem where I need a complex equation with many input matrices. Each matrix has an ID depending on its set (between 1 and 30, there are 100,000 matrices) and the result of each matrix is stored in a float[N] array where N is the number of input matrices.

After this, the result I want is the sum of every float in this array for each ID, so with 30 IDs there are 30 result floats.

Any suggestions on how I should do this?

Right now, I read the float array (400kb) back to the host from the device and run this on the host:

```
// Allocate result_array for 100,000 floats on the device
// CUDA process input matrices
// Read from the device back to the host into result_array
float result[10] = { 0 };
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    result[input[i].ID] += result_array[i];
}
```

But I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: Sounds like a reduction - study the reduction example in the CUDA SDK.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the word for it, I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `cublasSasum()` to do this - this is a bit easier than adapting one of the SDK reductions (but less general of course). Check out the CUBLAS examples in the CUDA SDK.